How to Autofill to Compare Dates
I'm working on a project where I'm trying to see if an event happening earlier (event a vs b) affects outcome x. I need to compare date a to date b. I am trying to use the Calculated Field to auto populate a response depending on if a or b happened earlier. Anyone have any suggestions on how I can do this? Thanks!
I tried "if/then" commands and it did not work. I also tried datediff and was hoping to set up dif answers depending on if the datediff is positive or negative, but that also didn't work.

For illustrative purposes, let's say the variable names of your dates are actually called [dateA] and [dateB]. You can use a text field that leverages the @CALCTEXT Action Tag. Let's also say for argument's sake that the variable you want to create that compares which date is earlier is called [is_earlier]. Then, you could write something like this in the field annotation/action tag dialog box for the [is_earlier] variable:
@CALCTEXT(if(
    [dateA]!='' AND
    [dateB]!='' AND
    datediff([dateA], [dateB], "d", true) < 0,
    # If difference is less than zero, Date B is earlier
    "Date B",
    if(
        [dateA]!='' AND
        [dateB]!='' AND
        datediff([dateA], [dateB], "d", true) > 0,
        # If difference is greater than zero, Date A is earlier
        "Date A",
        if(
            [dateA]!='' AND
            [dateB]!='' AND
            datediff([dateA], [dateB], "d", true) = 0,
            # If difference is equal to zero, neither is earlier/dates are the same day
            "Neither",
            # Else blank
            ""
        )
    )
)
)

This should update in real-time on the data entry form, and includes safeguards to make sure that neither date field is blank. This also assumes that the difference is in days; you can also substitute hours or minutes inside the datediff() function as the time unit of choice. Keep in mind you can also have @CALCTEXT print numbers instead of text (e.g., '1' instead of 'Date B'), but it'll still be considered a character data type underneath the hood. You can coerce this to a numeric data type in your statistical software of choice when it comes time to evaluate the effect on outcome X. Additionally, you can also eliminate the final nested if() statement if it's impossible for date A and date B to be the same date in your real data set.
